# How to Fix Incorrect Progress and Progress Percentage in the Upload Progress Bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload

I have created a multifile loading application where you can load multiple files and one upload button. After clicking the button, all files are uploaded with progress and percentages. Here is the problem I am facing: when we are clicking the upload button, the process of progress and the increasing percentages are not proper, and after the upload is completed successfully, the percentage should stop, but it keeps counting 10-100 again. So how do I resolve that progress bar issue that the progress bar percentage-wise should fill, and after completion, it says upload successfully and without select if we upload then it will say file should select?

```
import { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import axios from "axios";
import AttachFileIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AttachFile";
import LinearProgress from "@mui/material/LinearProgress";

export default function App() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState(null);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState({ started: false, pc: 0 });
  const [progressNum, setProgressNum] = useState(10);
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (progressNum <= 100) {
        setProgressNum((progressNum) =>
          progressNum >= 100 ? 10 : progressNum + 10
        );
      } else {
        return;
      }
    }, 800);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []);
  const handleUpload = useCallback(() => {
    if (!files) {
      setMsg("no file selected");
      return;
    }
    const fd = new FormData();
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      fd.append(`file${i + 1}`, files[i]);
    }
    setMsg("Uploading...");
    setProgress((prevState) => {
      return { ...prevState, started: true };
    });
    axios
      .post("http://httpbin.org/post", fd, {
        onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
          setProgress((prevState) => {
            return { ...prevState, pc: progressEvent.progress * 100 };
          });
        },
        headers: {
          "Custom-Header": "value",
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        setMsg("Upload successfully");
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setMsg("Upload Failed");
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);
  console.log(progress.pc < 100);
  const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    const selectedFiles = e.target.files;

    setFiles((prevFiles) => [...prevFiles, ...Array.from(selectedFiles)]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="contained" component="label">
        Upload File
        <input type="file" onChange={handleFileChange} hidden multiple />
      </Button>
      <Button
        onClick={handleUpload}
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        component="span"
      >
        Upload
      </Button>
      {Object.values(files).map((file) => {
        return (
          <div
            key={file.id}
            style={{
              width: "500px",
              padding: "8px",
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.05)",
            }}
          >
            <AttachFileIcon />
            {file.name}
            <div>
              {progress.started && (
                <span>
                  <LinearProgress
                    variant="determinate"
                    value={progress.pc}
                    color={progress.pc < 100 ? "primary" : "success"}
                  />{" "}
                  {progressNum}
                </span>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
      {msg && <span>{msg}</span>}

    </>
  );
}
```